# Font of tabs name, menus, pop up dialog isn't able to change, KDE

Tags: google-chrome, kde

I've recently updated the Chrome to the 80+ version and noticed it has the default UI font. Before i configured it to a **some mono font** and it was showed up as needed. 
Now i set font up to new one using **Settings->Appearance->Customize fonts** and don't see the changes. I've set up OS fonts also.

Is it possible to change it and see in tabs, dialongs, browser menus?
OS Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to change an appearance of windows using GTK, like the google Chrome.

It is changing through **System settings->Appearance->Application style->Gnome application style->Font**